# Lemma 5.6. of "Invitation to 3D vision"

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, rotations, matrix-exponential

I'm reading through [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FwfSBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=invitation%20to%203d%20vision&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-pKCXk-jUAhXOFsAKHWiIB8IQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=invitation%20to%203d%20vision&f=false). Which is full of linear algebra, and there're some aspects I'm not quite familiar with. Lemma 5.6. states the following:

[image]

Here given $T \in \mathbb{R}^3$ the hat operator is defined as

$$
\widehat{T} = \left(
\begin{array}{lll}
0 & -t_z & t_y \\
t_z & 0 & -t_x \\
-t_y & t_x & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The proof is below:

[image]

I don't understand rigorously the following snippet:

[image]

My attempt in understanding why is based on the exponential matrix, firstly because of eigevalues/eigenvector argument we have

$$
e^{\widehat{\omega} \theta} \widehat{T} \omega = \widehat{T} \omega
$$

we can represent the exponential as
$$
e^{\widehat{\omega} \theta}  = I + \sin (\theta) \widehat{\omega} + (1 - \cos(\theta) \widehat{\omega}^2 \Rightarrow e^{\widehat{\omega} \theta} \widehat{T}\omega  = \widehat{T}\omega + \left( \sin (\theta) \widehat{\omega} + (1 - \cos(\theta) \widehat{\omega}^2 \right) \widehat{T}\omega \Rightarrow
e^{\widehat{\omega} \theta} \widehat{T}\omega  - \widehat{T}\omega = \left( \sin (\theta) \widehat{\omega} + (1 - \cos(\theta) \widehat{\omega}^2 \right) \widehat{T}\omega
$$

Therefore I have the equality

$$
\left( \sin (\theta) \widehat{\omega} + (1 - \cos(\theta) \widehat{\omega}^2 \right) \widehat{T}\omega = 0
$$

From here I got stuck I don't know what to do to infer that $\widehat{T}\omega = 0$

Any thoughts about it? I would much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the eigenspace of $e^{\widehat\omega\theta}$ corresponding to $1$ is one-dimensional and spanned by $\omega$. The equation $e^{\widehat\omega\theta}\widehat T\omega=\widehat T\omega$ says that either $\widehat T\omega$ is an eigenvector of $e^{\widehat\omega\theta}$ with eigenvalue $1$ or is equal to $0$, which means that $\widehat T\omega$ must be a scalar multiple of $\omega$. On the other hand, you know from the properties of $\widehat T$ that $\widehat T\omega$ is orthogonal to $\omega$, but the only scalar multiple of *any* vector $v$ that is orthogonal to $v$ is $0$: $cv\cdot v=c\,(v\cdot v)=0$ iff $c=0 \lor v=0$.

Your approach works, too. Picking up where you left off, observe that for all $v$, $\widehat\omega v\perp\widehat\omega^2v$. Thus, the expression $$\sin(\theta)\widehat\omega\widehat T\omega+(1-\cos\theta)\widehat\omega^2\widehat T\omega$$ is a linear combination of two orthogonal vectors. For this to be zero, either $\sin\theta=1-\cos\theta=0$, or $\widehat T\omega=0$. The former possibility is eliminated by hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I was wondering is the argument I was trying to use completely wrong? Because what I wanted was trying to use some computation to show that. I understand your logic argument, however I don't know why I'm still puzzled.

Comment: @user8469759 To continue from where you left off, observe that $\widehat\omega v$ is orthogonal to $\widehat\omega^2v$.

Comment: Assuming still $\sin \theta = 1 - \cos \theta = 0$ what would be the contradiction if I'd assume $\widehat{T} \omega \neq 0$?

Comment: @user8469759 $\sin\theta=1-\cos\theta=0$ implies that $\theta=0$, which was excluded earlier: “Hence consider the case $\theta\ne0$.”